# NSSharingService won't compile for archiving

Tags: swift, macos, swift3, xcode8, macos-sierra

```
@IBAction func sendFeedbackPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let service = NSSharingService(named: NSSharingServiceNameComposeEmail)!
    service.delegate = self
    service.recipients = ["support@mydomain.com"]
    service.subject = "Feedback on \(productName) \(productVersion) build \(productBuildNumber)"
    let body = "Dear Mark, \n\n"
    service.perform(withItems: [body])
}
```

I can't archive one of my projects in Xcode. I get a compile error the let service declaration line that says: '(String) -> NSSharingService' is not convertible to '(String) -> NSSharingService?' Does anyone know how to solve this? When I run this App in Xcode it just compiles and runs and I don't have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Set the compiler optimisation for the Swift compiler to whole file optimisation. Compiling now works again.

For those interested Xcode 8 has been used.